# How do I connect my DSL socket?

Tags: wiring

[image: MID]

With the blue ones or the red ones connected to 3-4, I'm getting around 1Mbps, and I'm supposed to get 24Mbps. How do I connect these proper?

Comment: What do the instructions say? What are the terminal labels? Have you contacted your provider's help desk to ask them?

Answer (score 1):

You don't.   There are only two operational wires on a phone line.  "24Mbps" is the max possible from your provider, not the guaranteed minimum.  Most likely you are on a long run from the nearest repeater so the bandwidth at your house is drastically reduced.

Comment: There might other problems with the line that the OP will want his provider to check like dirty/loose connections/bad wires.  They can usually check the wires/connection in minutes to see if there is a problem.  I would call only 1Mbps on a 24Mbps connection a problem.